# Object error when retrying to set data labels for scatter plot in excel 2010 - What is going wrong in the below code?

Tags: excel, vba

The below is driving me crazy, would appreciate any help on the following line which is causing the problems.

```
Set CompanySeries = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Carbon Tax Impact on EBT").ChartObjects(1).Chart.SeriesCollection(1)
```

Full code also posted below.

```
    Sub ScatterPlot1()

Dim work_book As Workbook
Dim r As Integer
Dim i As Long
Dim objSelection As Range, obJSrcData As Range, objCategories As Range

Set work_book = Application.ActiveWorkbook
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Input").Select

Set objChart = Charts.Add
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=Input!$P$5:$P$19"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "=Input!$Q$5:$Q$19"
With objChart
    'Set properties
    .ChartType = xlXYScatter
    .Location xlLocationAsNewSheet, "Carbon Tax Impact on EBT"
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Text = "Carbon Taxation Impact on EBT"
    .HasLegend = False

    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "EBT @ Risk"

    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "EBT Margin Impact"
End With

Set objCategories = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Input").Range("P5:P19")
Set objSelection = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Input").Range("Q5:Q19")

Dim r1 As Range
    Dim CompanyNames As Range
    Dim CompanyCounter As Integer
    Dim CompanySeries As Series

    Sheets("Input").Select
    Set CompanyNames = Range("O5:O19")
    Sheets("Carbon Tax Impact on EBT").Select
    Set CompanySeries = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Carbon Tax Impact on EBT").ChartObjects(1).Chart.SeriesCollection(1)

    CompanySeries.HasDataLabels = True

    For Each r1 In CompanyNames

        CompanyCounter = CompanyCounter + 1
        CompanySeries.Points(CompanyCounter).DataLabel.Text = r1.Value

    Next r1

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the exact error message and number?

Comment: "'Run-time error '1004;
Application-defined or object-defined error"

Comment: Does `.FullSeriesCollection(1)` throw the same error?

Comment: I don't see where you actually add data to the chart?

Comment: Thanks Tim & Big Ben

I have amended above with code pasting in values. Unfortunately '''.FullSeriesCollection(1) ''' is still throwing same error.

Comment: Did you try running your edited code, because it looks like you're creating a new series before you've even created the chart.

Comment: Hi Tim - Apologies, pasted in the wrong section.The above is now how the code reflected in my module, and is running all the way down to the line which is causing the original problem. I have getting the run time error 1004 for application defined or object defined error. The code is managing to create the graph with titles et al, however it stumbles on the data labelling section.